# Where is the calculator from 10.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, calculator, gcalctool

The default calculator from Ubuntu 10.04 was perfect.  It was simple, yet powerful.  It had memory locations and when you switched between Hexadecimal and Decimal the number in the display changed to represent the value in the new base.

The Ubuntu 12.04 default calculator does not have a memory function, and the display does not change when you change base.

Is there a way to install the old calculator application, or is there an alternative that is similar?

Comment: There is an extremely powerful memory function called *"variables"* in the default **gcalctool**. Let us know if you need help on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not like the Ubuntu 12.04 calculator, so I would recommend the installation of Galculator, it's the default calculator of Lubuntu and it have this feauteres:

> It had memory locations and when you switched between Hexadecimal and Decimal the number in the display changed to represent the value in the new base.

---

**Screenshot and features**

[image]

1. Select the number base and it will change at the same time.
2. Save more then one number in the memory.

---

**Installation**

To install this calculator called Galculator run the following command at the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install galculator
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the preference. All functions are there. This is a screenshot from the default calculator

[image]

Go to Menu → *Programming* to enable this. There are other powerful functions too as @Takkat said in a comment.

Alternatively, You can try using `speedcrunch`. Do `sudo apt-get install speedcrunch` in a terminal

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the Calculator from 10.04 was gnome-calculator. Look for it in the software center.

Comment: The is no gnome-calculator at the repository.

Comment: It is the 'same' tool - `gcalctool`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try SpeedCrunch, which has [additional features](http://www.speedcrunch.org/en_US/features.html).